# How to create synthetic data for a decaying curve in order to extrapolate it beyond some point?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, python, extrapolation

In the following curve [image], I would like to extend the measurements beyond $x$=1 in order to have a better estimate of the green curve compared to red line.

Note: I do not have the analytical form of the function but only ($x$, $y$) data sets in the range (0, 1).

---

Additional Question:
What is the functional form of the following curve?
[image]

Comment: Fit the best curve and extend it analytically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One kind of function you may try to fit this is difference of exponential function, these two timescales controls the rising and decaying timescale of your data.
$$
f(t)=A\left(\exp(-t/\tau_1)-\exp(-t/\tau_2)\right) \theta(t)\\
$$
$H(t)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) $\theta(t)=1$ only when $t\geq 0$.

A plot using Wolfram Alpha $(\exp(-t/3)-\exp(-t/1)) \theta(t)$

[image]

Scipy's `curve_fit` could be used to optimize these parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It turns out that this is a good parametrization. Also, my main issue was that I was unable to find a good initial guess upon which the fitting highly depends.

Comment: Very good question! Onset timr t is easier to estimate. Decate and rising phase may need to guess by eye? Or if there arr domain knowledge of the system

Comment: Can you let me know if the curve is one shown in painting, what would be the functional form?

Comment: Just out of curiosity are you studying sth related to neurons? The wave form  looks quite remniscent of those

Comment: To answer your added question i think  subtracting a 3rd exponential with a slower time scale will do.

Comment: Tried it with curve_fit. It's not working.

Comment: Don't know how you implement these so there is no way I can help you fix the curve_fit problem in a chat...
One of my codes that did such fitting is linked. It worked perfectly for me at that time. 

https://github.com/Animadversio/Tone-Evoked-Potential-Data-Analysis/blob/466c9e5be34979a87938c9e54402b4ef2842cf69/PSPFitting.py#L24

Comment: It actually worked. My function just turned out to be very noisy as a result of the stiffness of the underlying DAE problem. Thank you for giving me a head start.

Comment: Great to hear that! cong